# open a local html file from web browser control in microsoft edge instead of internet explorer

Tags: c#, .net

open a local html file from web browser control in Microsoft edge instead of internet explorer. I am using below code, but it is opening in internet explorer.

```
m_webBrowser.Document.Window.Open(htmlFilePath,"", "menubar=yes,resizable=no;top=0", false);
```

Comment: Consider using [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) instead of the old IE-based WebBrowser control.

Comment: cant use WebView2 as browser control has no. of references and we cant change at every place...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

WebBrowser control is built-in Internet explorer and AFAIK does not provide a way to use Edge or any other browser. MS release WebView control to cater for Edge which you indicate you cannot use.

Since you mention you need to open local file, you do not need a browser control at all. You can open it using:

```
Process.Start("explorer", "file:///E:/index.html");
```

This will open the file in the user's default browser. This is approach I would prefer rather than forcing a browser on them.

If you are certain that users have Edge installed, you can replace `explorer` with `msedge.exe` in the line above.

If you do not know if Edge is installed, you can verify it by checking existing of registry key containing `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge` under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\PackageRepository\Packages`. This is of course dependent on operating system and can change with time and versions.

To avoid dependency on operating system, I would prefer to launch user's default browser.